# I want to use my username to post blog posts, is this advisable?

Tags: username

I only intend to post blog posts with a one word name (the name of the website), and so I am wandering can I just use my username??

Is this common amongst admin-bloggers to post using their username rather than any chosen name they might pick??

The reason I ask is because I do not know what username I would pick other than the one I intend to post with. The only possible reason people might not do this is for the added security of not showing your username.

Answer (score 0):

One can find the username of post author in multiple ways. For example, yoursite.com/?author=1 may reveal the username. Even though, it is easy to find the username, it is still **not** recommended to keep the username for posts. However, it is **okay** to do so.